# How to make changes made to an entity's attributes automatically cause a change in another entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have an entity named *Events* (parent entity) which contains the following attributes

1. EventID
2. EventStartDate
3. EventEndDate

which has 1-N relationship with another entity named *ChildEvents* which contains the following attributes

1. ChildEventID
2. EventID(lookup)
3. EventStartDate(read-only)
4. EventEndDate(read-only)

I have written a JavaScript code that auto-populates the *EventStartDate* and *EventEndDate* when the *EventID* is updated.

My question is this:

I have an `EventID = "A"` with `EventStartDate = "today"` and `EventEndDate = "tomo"`
and this is added to a `ChildEventID = "C_A"` and saved.

I go back to my Events entity and change the start date and end date on `EventID = "A"` to something else and save the same.

Now when I open the child event record `"C_A"` I do not see the *NewEventStartDate* and *NewEventEndDate* being updated automatically.

Am I missing something? Do I have to write a code for it? Because I thought it would get updated automatically.

Note: Both entities are customized entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good question! What you need to remember is that JavaScript only managed the client-side of the process. It means, a little bit incorrectly but easy to understand, that whatever you do using JS simulates what the user can cause by navigating in the GUI themselves.

If I got your question correctly, you want the data in an entity (read-only fields on the child entity) to get an update when an other entity (the start date on the parent entity) is updated.

The most robust and reliable way to do that is to add a plugin that reacts to the message *update* (and, of course, also to the message *create*) and do the magical update from there.

The downside of that approach is that the threshold for a beginner might be very, very steep. Especially if you lack experience from C#, registering steps/images, konfiguring and uploading assemblies etc. (First time I made a plugin, I managed to FUBAR our CRM server and it took an MVP two days to get it up and running again. And I've been coding C# since over a decade, haha.)

The upside is that once you've got it working, you can do pretty much anything with CRM. The limits are gone. If you intend on working with CRM, that's the way to go. It's a hard way but it's also the only, serious way, IMHO.

And if you need pointers on the plugin - check out the blogs. (Mine is the best, of course, hehe.) And keep on asking!

Comment: Thanks a lot Konrad! It really helps.Am new to CRM. Just like what you said, am afraid to register my plugin and mess up things that works properly, so I thought if i could find other ways of doing it, i would prefer those. But since plugin is the only way, I would try doing the same. Thanks for the wonderful insight! Will check out your blogs too. Thanks once again!

Comment: @user1639515 (1) Glad to be of help. (2) Check one of the replies as "answer" (preferably mine, haha. (3) Plugins are tricky but logical. You won't break anything (and if you do, we'll help you to remove the mistake, as long as you don't do stuff in the company's production environment). (4) Set up a "I'd-like-to-achieve" scenario and start asking. I wouldn't mind some extra reputation and...

Answer (score 2):

You want to make the parent update its children when the dates in the parent is changed? Then you should write a plugin (on the parent entity).

Answer (score 2):

I understand this: You want to update the child records of an entity based on the changes made in parent entity. If we assume this, you should use distributed workflow. [This link](http://crm2011distributewf.codeplex.com/) helps you. This is a straight forward solution which you could import and use easily.